# Match camera view with image

Tags: camera

I am working on an architectural visualisation where I would like to insert a new building project into an image from drone footage.

I have a rough, but accurate model of the sorruding landscape. I've manually matched the two views using a couple of houses as reference, but there is a lot of room for imporvement.

What technique is best to do this? Is there a way of automating it for higher accuracy and speed?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). There is a useful [addon called fSpy](https://fspy.io/) created for matching your camera position. I don't use it much myself, but YT has many tutorials on it.